# How to determine the name of the current working file in a regex operation?

Tags: command-line, bash

If I try to run a regex operation on files like so (example):

```
$ mv *.ext *.new.ext
```

That does not work.

How do I ensure that when I batch rename or perform an operation on multiple files that they keep their current name (not the extension, just the name)?

Note: I am not looking for something like the `rename` command because this has to work for *everything*, not just renaming files.

Note 2: Okay, these answers are good and explains things to me that I didn't properly understand before. Thanks!

The command in question I am trying to use is called `firmtool`, and is used in the 3DS homebrew scene.

It packs .bin files into .firm files and I would like it to run on all .bin files in a directory, packing them while preserving the original name.

Here is the syntax I need for the `firmtool` command:

```
firmtool build test.firm -n 0x23F00000 -e 0 -D arm9loaderhax.bin -A 0x23F00000 -C NDMA
```

where `test.firm` is the output and `arm9loaderhax.bin` is the input.

I want to run this command that if I have a directory with `test1.bin` and `test2.bin` that it produces `test1.firm` and `test2.firm`. Please let me know if I can use regular expression or a loop to complete this command. Thank you for any help!

Comment: " . . . because this has to work for everything, not just renaming files." As far as shell is concerned, `*` is always related to files in current working directory.  `*` in shell is **not** regex, but filename expansion.

Comment: That is not a regex operation. That is using globs/wildcards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm. You can't<sup>1</sup>, not universally.

`*` is a wildcard. The shell *expands* it. When you type

```
*.ext
```

The shell expands it to a list of all the matching files, like:

```
1.ext 2.ext whatever.ext
```

That is what is passed to the command, in your case `mv`. If `mv` receives more than two arguments, the last must be a directory, so

```
mv *.ext *.new
```

fails with `*.new` is not a directory, because `mv` is receiving a long list of arguments.

The shell itself does not support regex, but Linux has many utilities that do, like perl rename...

```
rename -n 's/(.*)\.ext/$1.new/' *
```

And remove `-n` after testing to really rename...

But you can capture the varying names in a variable and use it to loop over the files...

```
for f in *.ext; do echo mv -v -- "$f" "${f/.ext/.new}"; done
```

and remove `echo` after testing to complete the renaming... You can use almost any command with `for`, not only `mv`. Here's a slightly different example based on your question:

```
for f in *.bin; do
  firmtool build "${f%.bin}.firm" -n 0x23F00000 -e 0 -D "$f" -A 0x23F00000 -C NDMA
done
```

In this case `${f%.bin}` will expand to the value of the variable `f` with the suffix `.bin` stripped off (if it has such a suffix; otherwise it expands to the value of `f`).

See the manual on [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for other expansion types.

<sup>1</sup><sub>*waits to be proved wrong*</sub>

Comment: Nice explanation :-)

Comment: The process is called [*globbing*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), with [*glob patterns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Comment: @Zanna I well, if it's used within loop structure, like in `for f in ./*.ext . . .` like in my answer, then one can take a peak at currently processed file from the expansion. One can also use `strace` to view to what `*` wildcard expands, but otherwise you are right - not possible. Good answer, +1'd

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens and why does mv command fail

Let's actually examine what happens under the hood using `strace`.

```
$ touch file{1,2}.ext
$ strace -e trace=execve mv *.ext *.new.ext            
execve("/bin/mv", ["mv", "file1.ext", "file2.ext", "*.new.ext"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
mv: target '*.new.ext' is not a directory
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

As Zanna have explained in her answer `*.ext` will be expanded by shell to all files in current working directory that end in `.ext` string. What you see in that example is that `*.new.ext` is not expanded, exactly because there is no file that matches such pattern,i.e. there is no file `foo.new.ext` anywhere, hence shell passes that directly as argument.

The `mv` command in turn treats that as the following syntax:

```
mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
```

If you actually had an existing directory in the last argument, this would work

```
$ mv *.ext test_dir

$ tree       
.
└── test_dir
    ├── file1.ext
    └── file2.ext
```

#### What you actually want to do

Your original goal, as I understand it, is to rename every `*.ext` file to corresponding file with `.new.ext` ending. This can be done either with rename, as Zanna shows, or via looping in shell:

```
$ for f in ./*.ext ; do mv "$f" "$(basename "$f")".new.ext; done                         

$ ls
file1.ext.new.ext  file2.ext.new.ext
```

Notice the use of `basename` to extract the part before `.ext` and use of `./*.ext`. Use if `./*` is meant to prevent issues with filenames that may have leading `-` and is generally recommended approach instead of bare `*`

#### Additional notes

In your question you stated:

> If I try to run a regex operation on files

That's part of the problem. `*` in shell is Pathname Expansion, which expands to list of files in current working directory. It doesn't work in the same sense of regular expression `abc.*` where you match string starting with abc with any last character zero or more times.

> How do I ensure that when I batch rename or perform an operation on multiple files that they keep their current name (not the extension, just the name)?

You can iterate over the list of files using a `for` loop, and actively extract the filename using `basename` command, like I showed above. `prename` can be used, if you properly define substitutions in the regex expression. What's nice about `prename` is that it has dry run functionality (the `-n` switch), where no actual renaming is performed. Same idea can be used with iteration, where you use `echo` instead of `mv` first.

> I am not looking for something like the rename command because this has to work for everything, not just renaming files.

Again, `*` as far as shell is concerned deals with files in current directory. This is not the same as regular expressions. Your approach has to be tailored according to the tools you use.